# Python chain several functions into one

Tags: python, function, pipeline, chain

I have several string processing functions like:

```
def func1(s):
    return re.sub(r'\s', "", s)

def func2(s):
    return f"[{s}]"
...
```

I want to combine them into one pipeline function: `my_pipeline()`, so that I can use it as an argument, for example:

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.name = s
    
    def apply_func(self, func):
        return func(self.name)

rec = Record(" hell o")
output = rec.apply_func(my_pipeline)
# output = "[hello]"
```

The goal is to use `my_pipeline` as an argument, otherwise I need to call these functions one by one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a simple factory function or class to build a pipeline function:

```
def pipeline(*functions):
    def _pipeline(arg):
        result = arg
        for func in functions:
            result = func(result)
        return result
    return _pipeline
```

Test:

```
>>> rec = Record(" hell o")
>>> rec.apply_func(pipeline(func1, func2))
'[hello]'
```

This is a more refined version written with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72772478/combine-list-of-lambdas-in-a-single-one#72772550) using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

def pipeline(*functions):
    return lambda initial: reduce(lambda arg, func: func(arg), functions, initial)
```

I didn't test it, but according to my intuition, each loop will call  the function one more time at the python level, so the performance may not be as good as the loop implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a function which calls these functions:

```py
def my_pipeline(s):
    return func1(func2(s))
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution works for this specific case, but a solution to combine various number of different functions would be more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list of functions (so you can assemble these elsewhere):

```
def func1(s):
    return re.sub(r'\s', "", s)

def func2(s):
    return f"[{s}]"

def func3(s):
    return s + 'tada '

def callfuncs(s, pipeline):
    f0 = s
    pipeline.reverse()
    for f in pipeline:
        f0 = f(f0)        
    return f0

class Record:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.name = s

    def apply_func(self, pipeline):
        return callfuncs(s.name, pipeline)
        
# calling order func1(func2(func3(s)))
my_pipeline = [func1, func2, func3]
rec = Record(" hell o")
output = rec.apply_func(my_pipeline)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [quent](https://github.com/drukmano/quent) library for that:

```py
from quent import Chain

...

my_pipeline = Chain().then(func1).then(func2)
rec = Record(" hell o")
output = rec.apply_func(my_pipeline)
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of that library.