# Combine list of lambdas in a single one

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

What's the pythonic way to combine a list of lambdas in a single function? For example:

```
lambdas = [lambda x, k=k: x+k for k in range(3)]
```

I would like to get this all in a single lambda similar to this but without having to type it out:

```
f = lambda x: lambdas[2](lambdas[1](lambdas[0](x)))
```

Comment: Isn't the equivalent to `f = lambda x, n: x + sum(range(n))` ?

Comment: yes this is just an example, I have a general list of lambdas in practice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python chain several functions into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72498798/python-chain-several-functions-into-one)

Comment: You should use `reduce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) like below:

```
from functools import reduce
lambdas = [lambda x, k=k: x+k for k in range(3)]
# x = 0
reduce(lambda x, l: l(x), lambdas, x)
# -> l[2](l[1](l[0](x)))
# step_1 : x = x , l = lambda[0] -> lambda[0](x)
# step_2 : x = lambda[0](x), l = lambda[1] -> lambda[1](lambda[0](x))
# step_3 : x = lambda[1](lambda[0](x)), l = lambda[2] -> lambda[2](lambda[1](lambda[0](x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `reduce` function is defined to be exactly what you want. An alternative is to use a simple for loop.

```
def f(x):
    for func in lambdas:
         x = func(x)
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

to do this with a lambda seems kind of weird.

Is there any specific reason why we cannot:

```
def function_chainer(lambdas):
    def chained(x):
        for function in lambdas:
            x = function(x)
    return chained
```

This solution is not a one-liner, but it is pythonic I believe.

If you really need a one-liner, you can use functools.reduce:

```
lambda x: functools.reduce(lambda a, f: f(a), lambdas, x)
```

The first argument to reduce governs the way of applying each subsequent element, the second is the iterable (here - our iterable of lambdas) and the last one is the initializer - the first value we want to pass to those lambda functions.